# Forum MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, forum

I am building a basic forum with CodeIgniter and I am having trouble with two MySQL queries.

Here are my tables:

```
mysql> describe forum_posts;
+----------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id       | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| topic_id | int(11)          | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| user_id  | int(11)          | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| post     | text             | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| date     | timestamp        | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| ip       | varchar(15)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> describe forum_topics;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| category_id | int(11)          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id     | int(11)          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name        | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| importance  | tinyint(2)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe forum_categories;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order | tinyint(2)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

1) I want to select all categories and their respective latest posts
2) I want to select all topics from category with id X and show the last post whitin this topic.

This is what I've done so far

(1):

```
SELECT 
    C.*,

    T.name AS topic_name, 
    T.id AS topic_id,

    P.date AS post_date

FROM forum_categories AS C

LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT id, category_id, name
        FROM forum_topics
        ORDER BY id DESC
    ) 
    T ON C.id = T.category_id

LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT id, topic_id, date
        FROM forum_posts
        ORDER BY DATE(date) DESC
    ) 
    P ON T.id = P.topic_id

GROUP BY C.id
ORDER BY DATE(P.date) DESC
```

(2):

```
SELECT 
    T.*, 
    P.topic_id,
    P.id AS post_id,
    P.user_id,
    P.date,
    users.username
FROM forum_topics AS T
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT id, topic_id, user_id, date
        FROM forum_posts
        ORDER BY id DESC
    )
    P ON P.topic_id = T.id
LEFT JOIN 
    users ON P.user_id = users.id
WHERE T.category_id =  '1'
GROUP BY P.topic_id
ORDER BY 
    T.id DESC,
    P.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Basically my problem is that I cannot first ORDER the subqueries and then GROUP them.

Also I am not sure if these quesries are efficient enough. I am working about the subqueries. Are they gonna be slow?

Comment: This is not going to be slow.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any solutions to my issue?

Comment: What is your intended layout of the data? It appears you are over doing this if it will be a typical forum layout. The categories can go into an array by themself with the name/id. The topic query can access that array while showing results to find the category. You sort/ the topics query accordingly. Also what are you wanting to order and group? Order by post time DESC and group by topic? Seems straight forward if that is the intended outcome.

Comment: I am trying to list all categories and the latest posts in them. Edit: actually your suggestion for separate query for categories only is really good. I will have to fetch the topics with the latest posts in them separately and this seems to be much easier. Thanks! Great advice!

Comment: Most forum platforms are not normalized and their DB structure does some kind of pre-caching. The reason is that MOST queries display either a list of threads or a list of posts from a specific thread. E.g., in order to "select all categories and their respective latest posts" you should consider a "last_post_id" column in the "forum_categories" table. This will dramatically simplify your queries and improve performance. Another common example is to track the number of posts in a thread rather than counting the post_count for every thread every time the page loads.

Comment: There is a really good logic in your comment. I successfully implements the complicated solution, but I will refactor it in your way. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of breaking my head into the wall I think I found the solution for (1) and now it will be easier to find solution for (2).

```
SELECT 
    C.id,
    C.name AS category_name,
    C.order AS category_order,
    T.*

FROM forum_categories AS C

LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            T.category_id, 
            T.id AS topic_id, 
            T.name AS topic_name,
            P.user_id,
            P.username,
            P.date
        FROM forum_topics AS T

        LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT 
                    P2.id AS post_id,
                    P2.topic_id,
                    P2.user_id,
                    P2.date, 
                    U.username
                FROM forum_posts AS P2
                LEFT JOIN users AS U ON P2.user_id = U.id
                ORDER BY P2.id DESC
            )
            P ON P.topic_id = T.id

        ORDER BY P.post_id DESC
    )
    T ON T.category_id = C.id

GROUP BY C.id
```

Edit: Fixed a little bug in the (1) query and here is the (2) for those which want to accomplish the same as me:

```
SELECT 
    T.*,
    P.*

FROM forum_topics AS T

LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            P2.id AS post_id,
            P2.topic_id, 
            P2.user_id,
            P2.date,
            U.username
        FROM forum_posts AS P2
        LEFT JOIN users U ON U.id = P2.user_id
        ORDER BY P2.id DESC 
    )
    P ON P.topic_id = T.id 

WHERE T.category_id =  '1'
GROUP BY P.topic_id
ORDER BY P.topic_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to test, this is an idea i would try to start with. It may not be how others would do it, but the logic should at least help point you in a direction. I'm sure the critics will come out but ya know, no one is answering this so i figure i would try to get you going in a direction!

```
SELECT *
FROM forum_categories
$catArray ^^

SELECT p.*, t.*
FROM forum_posts p, forum_topics t, forum_categories c
WHERE t.category_id = c.id
AND p.topic_id = t.id
ORDER BY c.order ASC, p.date DESC
GROUP BY t.id
$postArray^^

for ($x = 0; $x < count($postArray); $x++)
{
    for ($y = 0; $y < count($catArray); $y++)
    {
        if ($catArray[$y]['id'] == $postArray[$x]['category_id'])
        {
            $catData = $catArray[$y];
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($catData['id'] != $currentCat)
    {
        PRINT CATEGORY >> $catData['name']
    }

    PRINT TOPIC >> $postArray[$x]['name']
    PRINT NEWEST POST >> $postArray[$x]['post'] 

    $currentCat = $catData['id'];
}
```